# How can I add multiple ints to a character array, then pull them out?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, char

I am trying to place 3 integers(byte size is 4) into a character string byte by byte using c. I then need to "extract" the integers out of the character array so I can do integer operations on them. I have looked around and could not find any solutions to this. I think this will require some type of pointer use or shifting, but I cannot figure out how to write it.

```
char str[12]="";

int a;
int b;
int c;

int x;
int y;
int z;


a=5;
b=7;
c=12;
```

I know that an int is 4 bytes. I would like to make it so the str char array has the following data in it.

```
str = |a1|a2|a3|a4|b1|b2|b3|b4|c1|c2|c3|c4|
```

*I do not want it like this. str=|'5'|'7'|'12'|

I then need to "extract" the integers out of the character array.

```
x=str[0-3];  //extracting a
y=str[4-7];  //extracting b
z=str[8-11]; //extracting c
```

After this, I should be able to write x=y+z and x will be equal to 19.

Comment: You have to convert the integer to string, using function such as sprintf(). Otherwise you cannot assign each digit to a different byte. Then do the assignment per byte just like characters in string. Latter  pass address of starting index like str[0], str[4], str[8] to atoi to get the coversion done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not well posed so you are getting different answers which may or may not be solving your problem. In my interpretation, here's what you need:

```c
int i1, i2, i3;
char arr[sizeof(i1)+sizeof(i2)+sizeof(i3)];

memcpy(arr, &i1, sizeof(i1));
memcpy(arr+sizeof(i1), &i2, sizeof(i2));
memcpy(arr+sizeof(i1)+sizeof(i2), &i3, sizeof(i3));
```

Note that I'm being deliberately explicit with using sizeof(i) instead of just "4". It is fairly safe that integers will be 32-bit in whatever environment you are using, but this is safer and strictly speaking more correct.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to treat `str` as an `int` array instead:

```
int* istr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(str)
```

Then you can use e.g.

```
istr[0] = a;
istr[1] = b;
istr[2] = c;
```

and

```
x = istr[0];
y = istr[1];
z = istr[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use `memcpy`:

```
int nums[sizeof str / sizeof(int)];
std::memcpy(nums, str, sizeof nums);

// Do work on nums here...
```

The `reinterpret_cast` approach is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Use `(void *)` to get a pointer to x, byte by byte

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int); ++i) {
  str[i] = (void *)(&x)[i];
}
```

This will copy the 4 bytes of x into str, one by one. (void *)(&x) casts x as a char* array (or void*, same thing), and [i] accesses the i_th byte of the array

then access elements of str the same way.
Do the same with y and z, and don't forget the offset

Comment: Would this work for y and z?

for (int i = 5; i < sizeof(int)+5; ++i) {
  str[i] = (void *)(&y)[i];
}

for (int i = 9; i < sizeof(int)+5; ++i) {
  str[i] = (void *)(&z)[i];
}

Comment: Of course, I tried to give you the idea of what was going on under the hood. just replace 5 and 9 by 4 and 8 and it will work

Comment: When I do this, it gives me errors. (strict) illegal conversion of pointer to char. (warning) conversion of pointer to char loses accuracy